# How to fix this error in Flutter " What went wrong: org/apache/tools/ant/DirectoryScanner > org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner "

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

**Why does this error occur when Run Without Debugging ?**

Launching lib\main.dart on SM A505F in debug mode...
main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  org/apache/tools/ant/DirectoryScanner

> org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

I created a new Flutter project and did Run Without Debugging. How to fix it ?